# How to include a local webpage in C# VisualStudio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to C# development and don't know a thing about how *resources* work. I need to include a whole offline website in my project and display it in `WebBrowser`. I've already copied the folder into my project directory but what URL should I use to reference it?

[image]

Is it included correctly or should be somehow marked as a resource?

Comment: You can't do this in a windows form application. I'd create a MVC project and when you run that visual studio will use IIS to make a local web server for you under local host. You can then navigate to it using http:/localhost:port/Website/index.html

Comment: Sounds a lot like an overkill... I just need to display the static html files.

Comment: You could just open the file with the file location. C:/../index.html without creating a localhost website maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just open the directly using it's whole path. This can be done using this code:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Website\index.html");
Browser.Navigate(path);
```

It takes the current directory of your program and appends the relative path of your file to it. Then it passes the resulting absolute URI to the WebBrowser.

Note however that this will work only if you [change the properties of the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251909/change-the-property-of-entire-files-in-folder-in-visual-studio-2008-project) so that all files inside will be marked as `Copy to Output Directory`. First you select all the files – only files, not folders! – in the Solution Explorer, then in Properties find `Copy to Output Directory` and set it either to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`. This will ensure that [all the files get copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a) to the `bin` folder, from which your program gets executed.

Comment: Sure I could, but the compiled code gets copied into `bin/Debug`, which means I can't use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. I could do `\..\..` but that doesn't *feel* like the right thing to do considering portability. Also the resulting program would be unusable in real-case scenario.

Comment: If you set it as a resource it will get built in the bin folder with the rest of the code. You can then access it via Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: But how do I mark a whole folder as a resource? The html files have relative links to images and scripts...

Comment: You can just mark the folder as copy to output directory http://stackoverflow.com/a/7358644

Comment: This is the answer I needed ;)